# Spring Security error 403 during authorization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I followed a tutorial on Spring Security. I have set up an authentication that works: here is my authentication filter.

```
package com.securitycrud.crudTest.filter;

import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;

@Slf4j
public class CustomAuthentificationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    public CustomAuthentificationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager){
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);

        return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        User user = (User)authentication.getPrincipal();
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret".getBytes());
        String access_token = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(user.getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+ 10 * 60 * 1000))
                .withIssuer(request.getRequestURL().toString())
                .withClaim("roles", user.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.joining()))
                .sign(algorithm);

        String refresh_token = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(user.getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+ 30 * 60 * 1000))
                .withIssuer(request.getRequestURL().toString())
                .withClaim("roles", user.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.joining()))
                .sign(algorithm);

        Map<String, String> tokens = new HashMap<>();
        tokens.put("access_token", access_token);
        tokens.put("refresh_token", refresh_token);
        response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), tokens);
    }
}
```

Then here is the authorization and config class.

```
package com.securitycrud.crudTest.security;

import com.securitycrud.crudTest.filter.CustomAuthentificationFilter;
import com.securitycrud.crudTest.filter.CustomAuthorizationFilter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import static org.springframework.http.HttpMethod.GET;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpMethod.POST;
import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;
import static org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS;

@Configuration @EnableWebSecurity @RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CustomAuthentificationFilter customAuthentificationFilter = new CustomAuthentificationFilter(authenticationManagerBean());
        customAuthentificationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/login");
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS);
        // en dessous: les url qu'on ne veut pas sécuriser par l'authentification: ex page d'acceuil

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/login", "/api/token/refresh").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/users").hasAnyRole("ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_USER");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(POST, "/api/user/save/**").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN");
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilter(customAuthentificationFilter);
        http.addFilterBefore(new CustomAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception{
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    }
```

```
package com.securitycrud.crudTest.filter;

import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static java.util.Arrays.stream;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN;
import static org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;

@Slf4j
public class CustomAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if(request.getServletPath().equals("/api/login")||request.getServletPath().equals("/api/token/refresh") ){
            filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
        } else {
            String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
            if(authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")){

                try {
                    String token = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer ".length());
                    Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret".getBytes());
                    JWTVerifier jwtVerifier = JWT.require(algorithm).build();
                    DecodedJWT decodedJWT = jwtVerifier.verify(token);
                    String username = decodedJWT.getSubject();
                    String[] roles = decodedJWT.getClaim("roles").asArray(String.class);
                    Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
                    stream(roles).forEach(role -> {
                        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, authorities);
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
                        try {
                            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                        } catch (IOException | ServletException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    });

                }catch (Exception exception){
                    log.error("error loggin in: {}", exception.getMessage());
                    response.setHeader("error", exception.getMessage());
                    response.setStatus(FORBIDDEN.value());
                    Map<String, String> error = new HashMap<>();
                    error.put("error_token", exception.getMessage());
                    response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
                    new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), error);

                }

            } else {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, when I try on Postman, I connect well, and I get the token well (and I am role user)

Then, I test the GET api/users request.
And there I can't. I get the following error:
403 Forbidden: {
"error_token": "The input is not a valid base 64 encoded string."
}

I don't understand.... I tried to search but no way...

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: are you sure in Postman when you make a GET request you pass your access token as Bearer authentication? This exception is raised in `DecodedJWT decodedJWT = jwtVerifier.verify(token);` call by constructor of the [`JWTDecoder` class](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/auth0/jwt/JWTDecoder.java#L46)

Comment: @AndrewThomas, yes I send Authorization in key, and for the value: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJDaGF0Iiwicm9sZXMiOiJST0xFX1VTRVIiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjgwODAvYXBpL2xvZ2luIiwiZXhwIjoxNjYyNjU1OTYxfQ.OMJQ_nVobmj56r5u8EqJYZ_3px2xCOiJ463spP3fkRw

Comment: I've tested without the hasAnyAuthority, but with permitAll and it worked

Comment: Any reason to why you are not using the built in JWT features of spring security instead of writing all that custom code https://thomasandolf.medium.com/spring-security-jwts-getting-started-ebdb4e4f1dd1

Comment: honestly I don't know what goes wrong: your jwt seems alright, it can decoded with HS256, but somewhere `IllegalArgumentException` is raised and auth0 library converts it to  `JWTDecodeException` with this message. Try to debug `JWTDecoder` and `JWTVerifier` class to see what goes wrong, or provide a link to your repo with code

Comment: And @Toerktumlare is right - you shouldn't waste your time trying to write custom security and debug its problems when Spring provides its own JWT support

Comment: hey guys, I will try to use the JWT library :) thanks again for your time, appreciated it

Comment: @Toerktumlare, i just read the medium poist, and yes it's easier. but i don't understand how to add authorities and roles with a user class... coud you have an example with authentification and a user class with roles ?

Comment: @Toerktumlare, could you send me a github project implementing the authorization (with medium's method) + authentification ?

Comment: Are the links to the github project in the post broken?

Comment: @Toerktumlare, no but it's only an authorization project :)

Comment: is the official spring security docs broken?